# How do I set up an FTP server for testing?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ftp, c#-3.0, console-application

I have written a code for uploading files on FTP Server. I don't have a server to test with.

How can I set up an FTP server to test the application?

Comment: setup an FTPd ... setup a passwot protected account ... upload stuff ... compare ... ?!

Answer (score 3):

Download and install an FTP server application like [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server). This will allow you to set up an what you need to test your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the IIS server as your FTP server.

See this link to learn how you setup an FTP server in IIS

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732769(v=ws.10).aspx